# Make div disappear when the page is scrolled to a certain point

Tags: html, css

I have the following block of code, characterising a div:

```
#posts{
position:absolute;
left:150px;
top:90px;
width:640px;  
}
```

And my problem is: when i scroll down, it goes beyond "top:90px". 
What I'm trying to do is: the part of the div's content which is above `top:90px` should be invisible.

The thing is... i can't use `z-index:(...)` because the only thing i have behind this div is the background.

Comment: Can you replicate this in jsFiddle? There is no way to make one small part of an element invisible (not that I know of anyways).

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {
$('#clickme').click(function() {
if ($(this).scroll() > 100) {
      $('#myDiv').hide('slow', function() {
              alert('Animation complete.');
      });
}
} else {
      alert('Error');
}
});
/*HTML*/
<div id="clickme">
test.
</div>
```

This will hide the div.

Comment: He doesn't want to hide the div. He wants to hide *part* of the div.